# Writing a file to another file in .c

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a code that reads file and then copies its content to the another file. I need to make it to copy only every 20 symbols and then skip 10 symbols and then again 20 symbols and so on.

I have to use lseek() function but I don't know how to put all of that in the cycle to do it.

```
main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    int fd1, fd2;
    int nbytes, mode;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    if(argc<3){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: nepareizs kopesanas parametrs\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if((fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Nevar atvert failu %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if((fd2 = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode))<0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Nevar izveidot jaunu failu %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    nbytes = lseek(fd1, 10, 0)
    while((nbytes = read(fd1, buf, BUFSIZ))>0){
            if(write(fd2, buf, nbytes) < 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "не понимаю\n");
                break;

            }

    }

    if (nbytes<0)
        fprintf(stderr, "не понимаю\n");
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Read in 30 byte chunks, but use only the first 20.

Comment: Why are you using an old style of C?

Comment: Because my teacher is ancient. He's been fighting for soviet union in red army. lol.

Comment: The magic numbers in `lseek(fd1, 10, 0)` are suspicious. Use the appropriate macros.

Comment: @JanisŠteinbergs  20 million dead and somehow, your teacher survived?  There is no justice in the world:(

Comment: @MartinJames and the worst part is that he's very proud of his achievements in the war. He's telling us half of the lectures about war and teaching OS from old russian book. He really aren't teaching, just telling what we have to do wit those functions and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
nbytes = lseek(fd1, 10, 0)
while((nbytes = read(fd1, buf, BUFSIZ))>0){
        if(write(fd2, buf, nbytes) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "не понимаю\n");
            break;

        }

}
```

with

```
while((nbytes = read(fd1, buf, BUFSIZ))>0){
        /* first you write your 20 bytes */
        if(write(fd2, buf, nbytes) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "не понимаю\n");
            break;

        }
        /* and then you move 10 bytes further */
        if (lseek(fd1, 10, 0) < 0){
            /* break if this is the eof */
            break;
        }

}
```

if BUFSIZ is 20.

or, simplest, with BUFSIZ = 30 :

```
while((nbytes = read(fd1, buf, BUFSIZ))>0){
    /* you only write the first 20 read bytes, or nbytes
       if there are no much bytes in the buffer */
    if(write(fd2, buf, nbytes < 20 ? nbytes : 20) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "не понимаю\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make `BUFSIZ 30` and `WRTSZ 20`, remove the whole second `if` block and `write(fd2, buf, WRTSZ)`? Seems like the easier solution and avoids the `lseek` call altogether?

Comment: He wanted to use seek, but that is true it must be the better solution. I'll write it.

Answer (score 0):

An additional alternative to consider. There are a number of good points mentioned in the comments to your question. Below the example collects the various comments and provides a concise way to read 30-bytes and write the first 20-bytes to an output file.

The use of all *magic numbers* (hardcoded values sprinkled throughout the code) are avoided. Both the read and write are validated, stream operations (e.g. `fread`, `fwrite`) are utilized instead of `read`, `write`) and the `close` of the output file is validated:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { WRTSZ = 20, BUFSZ = 30 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s ifile ofile\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *ifp = fopen (argv[1], "rb");
    FILE *ofp = fopen (argv[2], "w+");
    char buf[BUFSZ] = "";

    if (!ifp) { /* validate file open for reading (binary) */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!ofp) { /* valdate file open for writing */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    /* read BUFSZ bytes (require at least WRTSZ), and output */
    while (fread (buf, sizeof *buf, BUFSZ, ifp) >= WRTSZ)
        if (fwrite (buf, sizeof *buf, WRTSZ, ofp) != WRTSZ)
            fprintf (stderr, "error: fwrite of WRTSZ failed.\n");

    fclose (ifp);
    if (fclose (ofp))   /* validate close of output file */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: on close of '%s'.\n", argv[2]); 

    return 0;
}
```

(*Note*: Only full blocks of 20-bytes are written. If the last read is a partial read of less than 20-bytes, that information is not written to the output file. You can adjust the conditionals surrounding `fread` and `fwrite` to tailor the behavior to your needs.)

**Example Input File (non-POSIX, no eol)**

The following input file is text for example purposes, ant it contains no POSIX *end-of-line* (`'\n'`). (you can include the newline if you like, it will just result in a newline being written to the output file)

```
$ cat dat/ruler.txt
........10........20........30........40........50........60........70........80........90
```

**Use/Output File**

```
$ ./bin/rd30wrt20 dat/ruler.txt dat/rulerout.txt
$ cat dat/rulerout.txt
........10........20........40........50........70........80
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

**Writing All Bytes ( 0 < partial-bytes <= WRTSZ )**

If you want to write any partial bytes read during the last `fread`, you can adjust the conditionals to something similar to the following:

```
size_t rdsz;
...
/* read BUFSZ bytes, write 0 < rdsz <= WRTSZ */
while ((rdsz = fread (buf, sizeof *buf, BUFSZ, ifp)))
    if (fwrite (buf, sizeof *buf,
        rdsz > WRTSZ ? WRTSZ : rdsz, ofp) != WRTSZ)
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: fwrite of '%zu'.\n", rdsz);
```